# OpenCV2 error trying to convert images from RGB to YCrCb

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am attempting to prepare an image dataset for machine learning model and one of the functions I use resizes and changes the color, however I am met with the following error messages

```
  File "prepare_data.py", line 129, in <module>
    data, label = prepare_crop_data(DATA_PATH)
  File "prepare_data.py", line 70, in prepare_crop_data
    hr_img = cv2.cvtColor(hr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\ci\opencv-suite_1573470242804\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I have doubled checked that the images are contained within the paths I provided and I have tried using a different library to load them (io), but that doesn't seem to help.

Line 70 is within this function (I've commented above it):

```
def prepare_crop_data(_path):
    names = os.listdir(_path)
    names = sorted(names)
    nums = names.__len__()

    data = []
    label = []

    for i in range(nums):
        name = _path + names[i]
        hr_img = cv2.imread(name, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        # Line 70
        hr_img = cv2.cvtColor(hr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
        hr_img = hr_img[:, :, 0]
        shape = hr_img.shape

        # two resize operation to produce training data and labels
        lr_img = cv2.resize(hr_img, (shape[1] / scale, shape[0] / scale))
        lr_img = cv2.resize(lr_img, (shape[1], shape[0]))

        width_num = (shape[0] - (BLOCK_SIZE - BLOCK_STEP) * 2) / BLOCK_STEP
        height_num = (shape[1] - (BLOCK_SIZE - BLOCK_STEP) * 2) / BLOCK_STEP
        for k in range(width_num):
            for j in range(height_num):
                x = k * BLOCK_STEP
                y = j * BLOCK_STEP
                hr_patch = hr_img[x: x + BLOCK_SIZE, y: y + BLOCK_SIZE]
                lr_patch = lr_img[x: x + BLOCK_SIZE, y: y + BLOCK_SIZE]

                lr_patch = lr_patch.astype(float) / 255.
                hr_patch = hr_patch.astype(float) / 255.

                lr = numpy.zeros((1, Patch_size, Patch_size), dtype=numpy.double)
                hr = numpy.zeros((1, label_size, label_size), dtype=numpy.double)

                lr[0, :, :] = lr_patch
                hr[0, :, :] = hr_patch[conv_side: -conv_side, conv_side: -conv_side]

                data.append(lr)
                label.append(hr)

    data = numpy.array(data, dtype=float)
    label = numpy.array(label, dtype=float)
    return data, label
```

Line 129 is just when the function is called in the main function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data, label = prepare_crop_data(DATA_PATH)
```

Comment: error says `hr_img` is empty. check if that is true. check why it's empty. `print` the file path you are constructing. run your program in `pdb`, step through, look at variables. familiarize yourself with basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

@WhynarySearch this error means that the image you are passing is not load properly or its empty so checked the name in `hr_img = cv2.imread(name, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` each time you are running it and make shore about the path of image